# When I try to install the haskell platform on 14.04, I get unmet dependencies

Tags: dependencies

I couldn't install the Haskell platform on 14.04

`apt-get` or `synaptic` could not install the haskell-platform.

Error message below:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
haskell-platform :  depends on: libghc-gluraw-dev (>= 1.3.0.0) but it will not be installed
            depends on: libghc-gluraw-dev (< 1.3.0.0+) but it will not be installed
            depends on: libghc-glut-dev (>= 2.4.0.0) but it will not be installed
            depends on: libghc-glut-dev (< 2.4.0.0+) but it will not be installed
            depends on: libghc-opengl-dev (>= 2.8.0.0) but it will not be installed
            depends on: libghc-opengl-dev (< 2.8.0.0+) but it will not be installed
```

When I try to install the first dependency I follow a process that ends with:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl-dev

Note: selecting <<libgl1-mesa-dev>> instead of <<libgl1-dev>>
the following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgl1-mesa-dev: depends on: libgl1-mesa-glx (= 10.1.0-4ubuntu5) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1
     it will not be installed
```

So, what to do now?

Comment: Maybe relevant that my box is a 32bit system.

Comment: Use backticks "`" instead of quotes and your question looks much better!  ;)

Comment: Do you have any PPAs enabled? Can you provide the output of `apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-glx`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I am getting the same problem. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: @ajay: If you the same problem, refer to the answers here; otherwise [ask a new question](/questions/ask).

Comment: I followed the below answer and even the link suggested in the answer. No luck. If I ask a new question, I'm sure it'll be promptly marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of some conflicts with some PPA.

You could try what is suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa).

or, alternatively, use

```
sudo aptitude install haskell-platform
```

`aptitude` can offer some more suggestions to resolve dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to install haskell-platform using aptitude to resolve the dependency problem.